# Python log parser

Tags: python, parsing, logging

I have a large log with several commands (ending with ;) and their outputs (till END) like the following:

```
<blabla;

foo
...
...

END

<xyz;

...
...

END

--and so on
```

The requirement is to have separate files with command names like

```
blabla
xyz
```

and in each file should be their respective outputs.

So far I have:

```
def generateDicts(log_fh):
currentDict = {}
for line in log_fh:
    if line.endswith(";"):
       if line.endswith("END"):
          yield currentDict
       currentDict = {""}
   else:
      currentDict["text"] += line
yield currentDict

with open("logfile.txt") as f:
print list(generateDicts(f))
```

Please help.

Comment: 1) What is your question? 2) What is insufficient with your solution? Does it print an error? Does it fail to perform correctly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post says you need to write to files, but your example doesn't do any file I/O. Here is a program that opens, closes, and writes to files.

```
import fileinput

output = None
for line in fileinput.input():
    line2 = line.strip()
    if line2.startswith('<'):
        output = open(line2[1:].split(';')[0], 'w')
    elif line2 == 'END':
        output.close()
        output = None
    elif output:
        output.write(line)
```

Comment: where do I put the filename?

Comment: You put the filename on the command line. Save my program as "parse_log.py" and then run this command: `python parse_log.py logfilename.log`

Comment: I ran it. It generated a blank file with the frst command name. Here is the error I got: >python parse_log.py test.log
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "parse_log.py", line 9, in <module>
    output.close()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'close'

Comment: Did you run it against the example in your post? For me it runs perfectly against that input. It seems as if your must multiple ENDs without an intervening "<". Does every command have a `<` at the beginning of the line?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `re` module

```
import re
with open('test','r') as f,open('output','w') as f1:
    f1.write("\n".join(re.findall(r'\<(\w+)\;',f.read())))
```

Output:

```
blabla
xyz
```

However, if file size is too large, you can consider reading line by line from the file rather than read it as a whole.